# strange behaviour of sub function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am encountering strange problem with df.sub function in pandas. I wrote a simple code to subtract df columns with a reference column.

```
import pandas as pd
def normalize(df,col):
    '''Enter the column value in "col".'''
    return df.sub(df[col], axis=0)
df = pd.read_csv('norm_debug.txt', sep='\t', index_col=0); print(df.head(3))
new = normalize(df,'A'); print(new.head(3))
```

The output of this code is the following, as expected:

```
df:
             A  B   C   D  E
target_id                    
one        10.0  3  20  10  1
two        10.0  4  30  10  1
three       6.7  5  40  10  1

             A    B     C    D    E
target_id                          
one        0.0 -7.0  10.0  0.0 -9.0
two        0.0 -6.0  20.0  0.0 -9.0
three      0.0 -1.7  33.3  3.3 -5.7
```

But, when I put this as an executable in argparse, I get all NaNs !

```
import argparse
import platform
import os
import pandas as pd

def normalize(df,col):
    '''Normalize the log table with desired column, 
    Enter the column value in "col".'''
    return df.sub(df[col], axis=0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''Manipulate tables ''',
    usage='python3 %(prog)s -e input.tsv [-nm col_name] -op output.tsv',
    epilog='''Short prog. desc:\
    Pass the expression matrix to filter, log2(val) etc.,''')

parser.add_argument("-e","--expr", metavar='', required=True, help="tab-delimited expression matrix file")
parser.add_argument("-op","--outprefix", metavar='', required=True, help="output file prefix")
parser.add_argument("-nm","--norm", metavar='', required=True, nargs=1, type=str, help="Normalize table based on column chosen")

args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
if (os.path.isfile(args.expr)):
    df = pd.read_csv(args.expr, sep='\t', index_col=0); print(df.head(3))
    if(args.norm):
        norm_df = normalize(df,args.norm); print(norm_df.head(3))
        outfile = args.outprefix + ".normalized.tsv"
        norm_df.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t'); print("Normalized table written to ", outfile)
    else:
        print("Provide valid option...")
else:
    print("Please provide proper input..")
```

Output for this execution is:

```
python norm_debug.py -e norm_debug.txt -nm A -op norm_debug

             A  B   C   D  E
target_id                    
one        10.0  3  20  10  1
two        10.0  4  30  10  1
three       6.7  5  40  10  1

             A   B   C   D   E
target_id                     
one        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
two        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
three      0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I use, `Python version: 3.6.7, Pandas version: 1.1.2`. The first one (hard-coded) was executed in Jupyter notebook, while the argparse was executed in standard terminal. What is the issue here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you divide by one column `DataFrame` like:

```
new = normalize(df,['A'])

print (new)
             A   B   C   D   E
target_id                     
one        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
two        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
three      0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN


print (df.sub(df[['A']], axis=0))
             A   B   C   D   E
target_id                     
one        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
two        0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
three      0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Because parameter `col_name` is one element list like `[col_name]`, not string like `col_name`.

If not possible, you can change function by [`DataFrame.squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html):

```
def normalize(df,col):
    '''Enter the column value in "col".'''
    return df.sub(df[col].squeeze(), axis=0)
# df = pd.read_csv('norm_debug.txt', sep='\t', index_col=0); print(df.head(3))
new = normalize(df,['A'])

print (new)
             A    B     C    D    E
target_id                          
one        0.0 -7.0  10.0  0.0 -9.0
two        0.0 -6.0  20.0  0.0 -9.0
three      0.0 -1.7  33.3  3.3 -5.7
```

Or use solution from @[DYZ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725062/2901002)

Comment: This does not explain why the code works w/o `argparse`. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: `argparse`, the way the OP configured it, parses `-nm A` as `['A']`, not as `'A'`. But in the original version it is `'A'`. See my answer.

Comment: I explain problem, you get `argparse` solution. But problem is not elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`args.norm` has been parsed as a list `['A']`, not as a scalar `'A'` (because of the option `nargs=1`). Remove that option.